# How do I restore the cooldown time left I have previously stored?

Tags: godot, savegame

Wether I convert the timer's `.time_left` to an interger or a float it always gives me an error saying

`"Invalid set index 'time_left' (on base: 'Timer') with value of type 'float'."`

or

`"Invalid set index 'time_left' (on base: 'Timer') with value of type 'int'."`

here's the code:

```
if "unstuck_cooldown" in player_data:
    $Minimap/Unstcuk/UnstuckCDTimer.time_left = int(player_data["unstuck_cooldown"])
```

Comment: It seems `time_left` is read-only? https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_timer.html#class-timer-property-time-left

Comment: I think it should be possible to make `time_left` writable, I submit to your consideration proposing the feature at https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues

Answer (score 2):

The property `time_left` is read only.

If your time is not repeating, then it would be sufficient to create a new timer for the save `time_left` by setting its `wait_time` or passing the saved `time_left` to the `start` method. However, if you timer must repeat, that won't work correctly. So you would have to change `wait_time` on the first `timeout`.